# Why do I get "issuer is not trusted" when I try to login to Subversion from Perl?

Tags: perl, svn

I'm trying to log in to the subversion, I have stored permanently the certificate, but I keep getting this error:

> RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on `'/svn/QFlife/Projects%20DotNet/QFX/trunk/Clients'`: PROPFIND of `'/svn/QFlife/Projects%20DotNet/QFX/trunk/Clients'`: Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://vc.flife.de) at list.pl l

This is the code, that is responsible for auth:

```
sub getauth
{
    my $cred = shift;
    $cred->username($user);
    $cred->password($passwd);
}


my $ctx = SVN::Client->new
(
    auth =>     [    SVN::Client::get_simple_provider(),
                SVN::Client::get_simple_prompt_provider
                (
                    \&getauth,2
                ),
                SVN::Client::get_username_provider()
            ],
);
```

Could someone give me a clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are `$user` and `$passwd` defined in the context of `getauth`? Are they valid?

Comment: yes, these variables are valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an https connection which means that when establishing the connection, the server will send his certificate to the client. The client will check that the certificate is valid that is: the certificate's common name and the server URL match and that the certificate has been issued by a trusted authority. According to your message this is the problem.

So the solutions can be:

1. Add the issuer's certificate to the trusted issuers base
2. Configure the perl SVN library to ignore certificate issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you've permanently added the certificate, adding the ssl_server_trust_file_provider to your  auth list should do it:

```
my $ctx = SVN::Client->new(
    auth => [ SVN::Client::get_simple_provider(),
              SVN::Client::get_simple_prompt_provider(\&getauth,2),
              SVN::Client::get_username_provider(),
              SVN::Client::get_ssl_server_trust_file_provider()
            ],
);
```